# PS5 DualSense: disable bluetooth on PC

Tags: game-controller

I only have a PC, and I'm connecting the controller with a usb cable. How do I turn off the controller bluetooth (to reduce radiation near my groin), which is on by default (out of the box)?
Maybe a setting in the steam client?

Comment: If it connects via USB how do you know it is still radiating Bluetooth frequencies? The power is miniscule, entirely dependent on data actually being sent (not a constant transmission) and there is no documentation or studies that I know of that show links between bluetooth radiation and any real harmful effects.

Comment: Do you carry your phone in your pocket, or in a lead box? Then don't bother about the bluetooth on the controller.

Comment: As Tetsujin notes you should be far more concerned by other devices. Having a WiFi router nearby or a phone on your desk will probably radiate far more energy and even at a distance is probably more energy delivered to any given body part than Bluetooth would deliver up close. WiFi power is around 10 times the power of bluetooth for an average transmission and mobile phone data will be way beyond that. Then there's a good chance that the controller uses BLE which would be even lower power. Unless you live in a mobile/WiFi dead zone chances are you get more energy from those sources.

Comment: Since I don't know what's going on with Bluetooth--no studies either way--I prefer to err on the side of caution. I don't have a phone, and my router wifi is disabled (I connect with a LAN cable). Besides that, the consideration is not only how much a device is transmitting, but also how close it is to your body.